# How to write Kiwi test cases in for below mentioned IBAction

Tags: swift, unit-testing, testing, kiwi

I'm facing the issue to right test case for below mentioned function.

```
-(IBAction) returnToLogin:(UIStoryboardSegue*) segue {
  NSLog(@"kiwi tested");
}
```

I have tried different ways but it's pass the test case

```
   it(@"Should unwind segue", ^{
        NSNumber *actionMethod = @([_vc respondsToSelector:@selector(returnToLogin:)]);
        [[actionMethod should] beTrue];
    });
```

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

In the current implementation of `returnToLogin:` you cannot test much, as the method is not doing anything. If the method would perform some actions, like changing the view controller hierarchy, then you would be able to assert on that behaviour.

But take into consideration the following:

1. the signature of the `IBAction` is not correct, an `UIStoryboardSegue` cannot trigger an action.
2. controllers are a little bit difficult to test, mainly because it involves testing UI changes
3. try to refactor the logic that you want tested into business classes, and test those classes;
4. Apple added support for [UI testing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M_P2-YIe6Mk&feature=youtu.be&t=30m50s) since Xcode7 and iOS9, so if you want to test the UI you can use that